# Xamarin Froms Carousel Page gives Source not Found error while moving to previous Images

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Carousel page in Xamarin Forms Working Fine in iOS but in Android working only on "next" Images, But Scrolling Back to Previous Images (which shown before) images gives error "Source not found/ Available" error.
All images loaded from Images Bytes.

Here is my Code. (Source from URL is not working in Some Countries like KSA..)

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" Title=""
          x:Class="Prj.XAML.ImageCarouselPg" x:Name="CRV"  ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource primaryLight}" >

<CarouselPage.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate >
        <ContentPage >
            <ContentPage.Padding>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                    <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="0,20,0,0" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </ContentPage.Padding>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="10,5,10,5"  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource primaryLight}">
                <!--<Label x:Name="TxtCode" Text="{Binding Code}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Subtitle"/>-->
                <Label x:Name="TxtCode" Text="{Binding Code}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Subtitle" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label x:Name="Txtdesc" Text="{Binding Description}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding BrandImage}"  Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ></Image>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </DataTemplate>
</CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselPage>`
```

Loading Code Back end code

```
private async void PopulateImageListNew(DataSet dtImgList)
    {
        string Errstr = ""; string TblName;

        try
        {


            if (dtImgList != null)
            {

                if (dtImgList.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dtImgList.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string Code = dtImgList.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Code"].ToString();
                        string ImageName = dtImgList.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
                        string ImageURL = dtImgList.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ImageUrl"].ToString();


                            byte[] byteArray = (byte[])(dtImgList.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Image1x"]);

                             Stream strm = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                             Brandimg.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return strm; });



                        ImageList.Add(new Models.OurBrands { Code = Code, Description = ImageName, 
ImageUrl = ImageURL, BrandImage = Brandimg.Source });

                    }
                }
            }

            CRV.ItemsSource = ImageList;
            //BindingContext = this;

            if (CurIdx >= 0)
            {
                CRV.SelectedItem = ImageList[CurIdx];
            }
        }
        catch (WebException WebEx)
        {
            WebErrStr = WebEx.Message.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            WebErrStr = Ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            WebErrStr = Errstr;
         }
    }
```

Class

```
public class Brands

{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public ImageSource BrandImage { get; set; }

    public string VideoUrl { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Did the url of image source has prefix `https` ?

Comment: Image source not from URL , loading from Bytes in Android. from URL is working fine, but in KSA (Saudi Arabia ) not working . So i changed to loading from bytes. Stream strm = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                                Brandimg.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return strm; });

Comment: If you had solved the issue ,you can post your answer and accept it . Which will help more people .

Comment: not solved yet. loading from stream still giving error

Comment: Did it return a null value ?

Comment: first time it loading perfectly. then we can move next  1,2,3,4.when we trying previous images(4,3,2,1) after moving forward, it is not displaying. we can move 1 ,2,3,4,5  moving back 5,4,3,2,1 , the images 4,3,2,1 will not showing

Comment: Since it works fine when first loading,maybe the logic has some problem.